# How to create image gallery and integrate it to lightbox2

Tags: media, javascript

I have a content type *Product* with a field *Images*. There are 4 photos. When i go to the product-node page i want to click on one of the photos (1 of 4) and open a popup/modal window where i would like to see all 4 photos (not only 1, as  Lightbox does). How can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using [Colorbox](https://www.drupal.org/project/colorbox) module.

> Colorbox is a light-weight customizable lightbox plugin for jQuery.
>   This module allows for integration of Colorbox into Drupal. Images,
>   iframed or inline content etc. can be displayed in a overlay above the
>   current page.

[How to use ?](https://vimeo.com/19386122)